# Enabling 10QPS vs 1QPS on Google AppEngine (Google Analytics)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-analytics

I saw that per the [Configuration and Reporting Limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas) it's possible to obtain more than 1 Query per Second

> In the Developers Console this quota is referred to as the per-user
>   limit. By default, **it is set to 1 query per second (QPS) and can be
>   adjusted to a maximum value of 10. If the per-user limit is set to a
>   value larger than 10 QPS**, the Google Analytics quota policy will
>   still take effect and limit per-user requests to 10 QPS.

I was unable to find where that might be done in the Console so was hoping for some help on where it might be. I've searched everywhere and asked on #appengine to no avail.

I'm attempting to access via. python/pandas, and just to confirm I was getting only one query per second I ran a few tests and the general runtime of any query was 0.9*n where n was the number of queries I ran (I a loop of queries that iterated over a date range to escape Google's 10,000 records per query limit.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developer console start page: https://console.developers.google.com/start

1. Click `Enable and Manage APIs`. It should be in a blue box.

   - If you haven't done so already it will prompt you to select a project.
     [image]
2. Search for `Analytics`

   - if you haven't done so already it will prompt you to enable the API.
3. Click `Quotas`
   [image]

Once there you can see the default `1 query per second` **Per-user Limit**.
And you can also see a link to a form to apply for a quota increase - read the form carefully and answer every question.

And finally you linked to the deprecated reporting API limits and quota page. It is mostly the same but the [V3 Core Reporting API Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas) will have the most up to date information.

Comment: Matt thank's so much, this is really really helpful. I was able to find the request form for increased API limits. However, it looks as though the form only allows me to request increases on the 50,000 requests/day and the 500 write/limits per day. I remember vaguely reading through the API limits and quotas documentation that in order to obtain the 10 queries/s number you had to associate it with a single IP. Is that something I need to do and how would I go about doing that? Or is it something else. Thanks again!

Comment: You might be referring to the `userIp` parameter, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/parameters#userIp "Lets you enforce per-user quotas when calling the API from a server-side application."

Comment: I think that's what I had meant. I'm not sure how to pass this through a request however. Nor how to get the request from 1 query per second up to 10 queries per second. Do you have any insight there?

Comment: If you are using the python client library you simply need to pass in the an additional query parameter. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/standard_parameters If you show your code it might help. as for changing it from 1 to 10 QPS click the pencil "edit" icon pictured above and it will allow you to edit QPS to 10.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm running a query using pandas and their pandas.io.ga.read_ga object. I attempted to edit the 10 QPS number but entering any number over 1 makes it so that you can't hit save. Like [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/9kl8XH6LxhMv9YXJN5M16xKMuHbAf6LzTgU91KjMnUs)

Comment: I realize now that I might be able to pass the additional userIP as one of the `kwargs` but I'll have to study the whole process in pandas because there's no support for that yet. If I did pass that, how would I make it in the console such that a specific userIP had a certain query per second request, and would that work as a substitute to editing using the pencil as above?

Comment: The developer console had a temporary issue where you could not adjust the Analytics API per user limit above 1 QPS, this has now been fixed.